# Java Final Getters

Tags: java, final, getter

Given the following class:

```
public class SomeClass {

    private final int a;

    public SomeClass(int a) {
        this.a = a;
    }

}
```

Which is more appropriate in terms of *completeness*?

```
public final int getA() {
    return a;
}
```

**OR**

```
public int getA() {
    return a;
}
```

In my opinion, both are equivalent, so I wouldn't even bother putting `final`.

But for the sake of being complete, the first method seems more "correct" than the second.

Comment: You accepted an answer so quickly, have all your doubts been solved? I was just about to give you another solution.

Comment: @user3437460 I accepted rgettman's answer since it cleared up my misconceptions about final methods. So I guess in terms of trying to answer my own question, I would say that the second method would be most correct in most situations.

Comment: Worrying about "completeness", more often than not, is just a distraction from whatever problem is that you are trying to solve.  People love symmetry, but don't write extra code just to make things symmetric.  Every line of code that you write becomes a liability.  Don't write any more lines than you _need_ to write in order to solve the problem at hand.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The keyword `final` means something completely different when applied to a method as opposed to applied to a variable.

On a method, it means that [no subclass can override the method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html).  It has nothing to do with not changing a value.  So, your two choices are not equivalent, because of whether a subclass may override `getA()`.

Comment: Interesting, must've missed this point when teaching myself Java :). So let's say I wanted to return a `final int` for whatever reason. How would one do that?

Comment: The method cannot force the return value not to be changed.  Even if you declare a local variable to be `final` and return it, the caller receives a mutable copy anyway.  However, the caller can enforce it, by declaring the variable to which it assigns the returned value `final`, e.g. `final int result = foo.getA();`.

Comment: @budi, there is no such thing as a "final int."  When you write `final int foo;`, you are saying two things:  You are saying that the variable `foo` holds an int value, and you are saying that the variable may not be updated.  `foo` is `final`, and `foo` is of type `int`, but there is no connection between the `final` and the `int`.

Comment: final methods are faster, because the JVM can call the method directly. When a method is Overrideable,  it have to search it in the class of the object which could be slower.

Comment: Be aware that when you also use nowadays Kotlin in your project the "final" protection can be bypassed by using extension functions.

Answer (score 7):

When you apply `final` on different things in Java, it gives you an almost totally different meaning.

> `final on variables`: Values cannot be assigned to it.
>
> `final on methods`: Methods cannot be overridden by sub-classes
>
> `final on classes`: That class cannot be extended by another class.

Hope that gives you something clear.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html)

> You can declare some or all of a class's methods final. You use the
>   final keyword in a method declaration to indicate that the method
>   cannot be overridden by subclasses.

So it depends on what you mean by completeness. *Practically* however, it really depends on whether you want the `getters` to be overridden.